# Is it possible to write XML file hosted on website using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I am facing a problem regarding writing xml file.

My browser is IE9.

I have a vbscript which writes xml file on local machine.
But when i try to write an XML file hosted on website with same code by just changing the file path, i am getting error.

here is a snippet of my code

```
FileName="http://www.samplewebsite.com/Filename.xml" 
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load(FileName)
/*Logic to write xml file*/
xmlDoc.Save FileName
```

So my question is

Is it possible to write XML file hosted on website using vbscript? if yes, how?

Comment: I am getting error "The parameter is incorrect" at "xmlDoc.Save FileName"

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).